# Sublime read function from require files then autocomplete

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I have sublimetext3.
I would like sublime, to read functions from other files, and give hints when I'm writing code:

File functions.js:

```
function someFunction(var) {
  console.log(var);
};
```

File app.js:

```
myFunctions = require('functions.js');
myFunctions.someFun... //I want sublime to give hints to autocomplete.
```

Any ideas how to do this?
Regards! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) is for. It is available through Package Control, so you'll need to [install](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) it first, if you haven't already.

There is extensive documentation both on the link I gave, and in many questions here on SO. I'd recommend copying the `Settings-Default` file over to the `Settings-User` file (both available under `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeCodeIntel`), and editing it there, as the `Default` file is read-only. In the `"codeintel_config"` section of the bottom, I'd recommend using the following JavaScript options at a minumum:

```
"JavaScript": {
    "javascriptExtraPaths": ["/path/to/libs", "/more/node/libs/"], // etc.
    "codeintel_scan_files_in_project": true,
    "codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth": 25
},
```

One key thing to remember when using SCI for the first time is that it can take a little while to index everything, especially if you have a large project or a large standard library (like Ruby and Python do). In the past, I've occasionally found it necessary to actually quit and restart Sublime a few times to kickstart the indexing and code completion, but once it's going you'll wonder how you got along without it.

Good luck!